# Powershell throws error when running npm start / npx tsc

Tags: node.js, typescript, powershell, express, npm

I am trying to run a simple npm start from the powershell command in a express - typescript project. And I'm getting this error

```text
/mnt/host/c/Users/-/AppData/Roaming/npm/node: line 8: /mnt/host/c/Users/-/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js: not found
```

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "express-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": \[\],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "typescript": "4.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.18.2"
  }
}
```

[image: File directory]

This is the node file config inside npm/node

```sh
\#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
*CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

"$basedir/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js"   "$@"
exit $?
```

The thing is with git bash I have no problems but powershell is my main editor. I tried reinstalling Node, closing everything, restarting.
I don't know why node is looking for nodemon and even if I install the dependency globally it doesn't work. Any suggestion?
Same thing happens if I try to run `npx node`, `npx tsc`, etc.

Comment: Where does the `/-/` in the paths come from? Instead of `-`, there should be username.

Comment: It's just my username but I changed it to a ' - ' .